# "Object of class Zend_Db_Table_Rowset could not be converted to string" in ZF

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have a problem with a query using MySQL and Zend Framework. I want to display an `<option></option>` with data from a database.

Using Zend, here what I've done. In my view helper:

```
public function bloc15()
    {
        $bdd_boutiques = new Front_Model_DbTable_Boutiques();
        $this->view->boutiques = $bdd_boutiques->fetchAll($bdd_boutiques->select()
                                                                         ->distinct()
                                                                         ->from('boutiques',
                                                                            array('ville'))
                                                          );


        return $this;

}
```

And in my view :

```
<form>
    <select id="editorsSelect" onchange="request(this);">
       <?php 
       foreach($this->boutiques as $bdd_boutiques)
       {
       ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $this->boutiques; ?>">
           <?php  echo $this->boutiques; 
           ?>
           </option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>                            
    </select> 
  </form>
```

I know the mistake should be obvious, but im starting with php and zend. Thanks all!

Edit: 
Thanks for your help, as i said, im realy bad in php. I succeded by doing that, but I'm not sure it's quite correct:

```
  <?php
                        foreach($this->ville as $bdd_boutiques)
                        {
                        echo $this->escape($bdd_boutiques->ville);
                        }
            ?>
```

and

```
 $bdd_boutiques = new Front_Model_DbTable_Boutiques();
        $this->view->ville = $bdd_boutiques->fetchAll($bdd_boutiques->select()
                                                                                 ->distinct()
                                                                                 ->from('boutiques',
                                                                                    array('ville'))
                                                                  );


        return $this;
```

Comment: Whats the problem you getting on?

Comment: ( ! ) Catchable fatal error: Object of class Zend_Db_Table_Rowset could not be converted to string ..\application\modules\front\views\helpers\scripts\bloc15.phtml on line 13

Comment: line 13 : <option value="<?php echo $this->boutiques; ?>">

Comment: Hi there. Please add error messages and all other important information _in_ the question. If you forget something, that's okay - just edit the question. Also, if you can make titles as useful as possible, that's great - it is much more helpful on the front page than a list of "Please help me with this" titles `:)`. Thanks.

Comment: Ok no problems next time i'll try ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through $this->boutiques and inside loop you are again using same variable $this->boutiques

```
   <option value="<?php echo $bdd_boutiques; ?>">
     <?php echo $bdd_boutiques; ?>
   </option>
```